Read value of key from one json file to another json file
I am doing Cypress automation with JavaScript. In this, I want to read value of one JSON file to another JSON file. And based on that want to retrieve other values.
Below is my credentials.json file:
{
    "url": "site.url",
    
    "sausername": "sausername",
    "sapassword": "sapassword",
    
    "viewonlyusername": "vouusername",
    "viewonlypassword": "voupassword",
}

In the above file, I pass the URL of different environments where I want to run my scripts. 'sausername', 'sapassword', 'viewonlyusername' and 'viewonlypassword' are credentials of different users.
Below is the SuperAdminTestData.json file, which includes required test data for super admin script.
{
    "accountName": "account name",
    "PartnerAdminAccount": "Automation Partner",
    "WholesalePartnerAccount": "Automation Wholesale Partner",
    "mitelAccountName": "Platform name",
    "siteName": "site name"
}

Now I am using this data in SuperAdminSpec.js file as below:
describe("Super Admin - User Roles and Permissions", function () {
let superAdminTestData, credentials
before(function () {
    cy.fixture('credentials').then(function (testdata) {
        credentials = testdata
    })

    //Get test data from 'superAdminTestData' file
    cy.fixture('superAdminTestData').then((testData) => {
        superAdminTestData = testData
    })
})

it("Login with valid credentials", function () {
    loginfunction(credentials.url, credentials.sausername, credentials.sapassword) //data from json file
})

it('Navigate to Partner Admin account', function () {
    //Click on all customer dropdown
    clickAllcustomers()
    //Navigate to Partner Admin Account
    clickCustomer(superAdminTestData.PartnerAdminAccount) //data from json file
})

})
In this structure, when I want to run my scripts on a stage environment, I have to go and manually change all data in both JSON files (Actually I have more than two JSON files which require changes).
Requirement: I want to add an extra key and value "environment": "stage". So when I want to run my data on stage I just have to change value of that key only from test to stage and vice versa. If I pass stage, it will take value for stage.
Question: Can I read value of one JSON file into another? If yes, how? If I pass the stage as value of environment key in credentials.json file, I want to get value of stage from test data JSON file if I structure the code as below:
(structure is not proper. This is the example that I want.)
credentials.json
{
    "environmnet": "Stage",
    "stage": {

    },
    "Test":{

    }
}

SuperAdminTestData.json
{
    (If the environment is stage it takes data of stage and so on. And also want to use that data into spec.js file.)
    "stage":{
        "accountname": "abc"
    },
    "test":{
        "accountname": "xyz"
    }
}

Please note that I am a beginner in Cypress as well as in automation.
I have not tried anything. But yes go through some solutions from Google and stack overflow as well:

Key from one Json file to value of another Json file using node/Javascript
Jq - add a key/value to one JSON file if such key/value exists in another JSON file

but I can't understand it. Please help me. Thanks!

It's not clear what the issue is. Please revise the question, remove the irrelevant details. Also please fix the mistakes in the code formatting.

From my end, nothing is unnecessary. Points and codes I have mentioned are shows you where I am using json values. And my question is to read value of one json file into another. But how not clear. Like I by adding new key 'environment' in cresentials.json file, I want to take value of stage environment from 'SuperAdminTestData.json' file. But how to structurised this code and How am I use this. really don't know.

JSON files cannot contain business logic that gets executed, so you cannot inject/merge the values from one file to another.
That being said, you can change the structure of the configuration so that it's grouped by another property which contains the name of the environment those values are for. From there you can access them using array notation with the environment name. Here's a working example of how to do this:
// in your config JSON file...
{
  "dev": {
    "url": "site.dev.url",
    "sausername": "sausername-dev",
    "sapassword": "sapassword-dev",
    "viewonlyusername": "vouusername-dev",
    "viewonlypassword": "voupassword-dev",
  },
  "stage": {
    "url": "site.stage.url",
    "sausername": "sausername-stage",
    "sapassword": "sapassword-stage",
    "viewonlyusername": "vouusername-stage",
    "viewonlypassword": "voupassword-stage",
  }
}



// This data should be retrieved from the JSON file. It's hard-coded here for this example
const configuration = {dev:{url:"site.dev.url",sausername:"sausername-dev",sapassword:"sapassword-dev",viewonlyusername:"vouusername-dev",viewonlypassword:"voupassword-dev"},stage:{url:"site.stage.url",sausername:"sausername-stage",sapassword:"sapassword-stage",viewonlyusername:"vouusername-stage",viewonlypassword:"voupassword-stage"}};

// in your Cypress code (assuming 'configuration' is a reference to the retrieved JSON)
const environment = "stage"; // set the environment name here
const credentials = configuration[environment]; // set the environment object to access here

const loginfunction = (url, username, password) => console.log(url, username, password);
loginfunction(credentials.url, credentials.sausername, credentials.sapassword)




Thanks for your reply, I have few questions: 1) Can we declare variable in JSON file? I tried after your answer but it is showing an error. 2) How we restructure 'SuperAdminTestData.JSON' file? Because values will be changed for stage/test environment. And if we restructure in a same way as you mentioned for 'Credentials.json', how we pass environment value there? Thanks!

Can we declare variable in JSON file? No. I've updated my answer to make it clear that the JSON should be retrieved from the external file, not placed in to a variable in the Cypress logic. How we restructure 'SuperAdminTestData.JSON' file? You don't. You have 1 JSON file with all necessary values per environment - ie. the first code example in my answer.
